# Java divide and conquer algorithm stack overflow error

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to find out the index of the smallest number in an int array using divide and conquer and I have this stack overflow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StrictMath.floor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Math.floor(Unknown Source)
```

This is my divide and conquer method:

```
private static int dC(int[] a, int f, int l) {
        if(f == 1)
            return f;
        if(a[dC(a, f, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)))] > a[dC(a, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)+1), l)])
            return dC(a, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)+1), l);
        else
            return dC(a, f, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)));
    }
```

Here is what I put in my main method:

```
int[] a = {35,30,40,50};

System.out.println(dC(a, 0, 3));
```

Comment: Just check the source for binary search, and base your own code off that.

Comment: Unrelated: use name that mean something. a, f, l, they all mean **nothing**. You dont write code to make the compiler happy, you write code so that *humans* can read and understand it.

Comment: Integer division (7 / 2 == 3) without `floor` and `(double)` cast is better suited.

Comment: `(int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2))` is the same as `(f+l)/2` (assuming `f+l` is non-negative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your stoping "rule"

```
private static int dC(int[] a, int f, int l) {
        if(l == f) // <-- This mean you have one item, so you want to return it.
            return f;
        if(a[dC(a, f, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)))] > a[dC(a, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)+1), l)])
            return dC(a, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)+1), l);
        else
            return dC(a, f, (int)(Math.floor((double)(f+l)/2)));
    }
```

Also, I would try to do the calculation only once, so something like this (also what Joop Eggen said about Integers arithmetics):

```
private static int dC(int[] a, int f, int l) {
        if(l == f)
            return f;
        int m = (f+l) / 2;
        int left = dC(a, f, m);
        int right = dC(a, m+1, l);
        if(a[left] > a[right])
            return left;
        else
            return right;
    }
```

Comment: oh yea I found out that that i put (f == 1) instead of (f == l)

Answer (score 2):

This is just the classical binary search problem.  From what I can glean by looking at your code, you seem to be getting bogged down in the logic used to make each recursive call to the left and right subarrays of the current array.  The logic I used below is to take everything from the start to (start+end)/2 for the left recursion, and everything from ((start+end)/2) + 1 to end for the right recursion.  This guarantees that there would never be any overlap.

The base case occurs when the algorithm finds itself sitting on a single entry in the array.  In this case, we just return that value, and we do not recurse further.

```
private static int dC(int[] a, int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) return a[start];

    int left = dC(a, start, (start+end)/2);
    int right = dC(a, ((start+end)/2) + 1, end);

    return left < right ? left : right;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] a = {10, 3, 74, 0, 99, 9, 13};
    System.out.println(dC(a, 0, 6));   // prints 0
}
```

### Demo

Note: I have no idea what role `Math.floor` would be playing here, since you're using arrays of *integer* numbers, not doubles or floats.  I removed this, because I saw no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical problem locating the index to the `min/max`, you can try it as:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = generateArrays(100, 1000, 0, 10000, true);
    int minIndex = findMinIndex(arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
    int theMin = arr[minIndex];
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(String.format("The min located correctly: %s", arr[0] == theMin));
}

private static int findMinIndex(int[] a, int l, int r) {
    if (r - l < 1) return l;
    int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
    int lIndex = findMinIndex(a, l + 1, mid);
    int rIndex = findMinIndex(a, mid + 1, r);
    int theMinIndex = l;
    if (a[lIndex] < a[theMinIndex]) theMinIndex = lIndex;
    if (a[rIndex] < a[theMinIndex]) theMinIndex = rIndex;
    return theMinIndex;
}
```

And the helper to generate a random array.

```
public static int[] generateArrays(int minSize, int maxSize, int low, int high, boolean isUnique) {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int N = random.nextInt(maxSize - minSize + 1) + minSize;
    if (isUnique) {
        Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
        while (intSet.size() < N) {
            intSet.add(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
        }
        return intSet.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    } else {
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```